# Is there a reason to use Android Constraint Layout Chain now that Flow exists?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

From what i have experienced the capabilities of Flow are a superset of those of Chains.
Therefore i'm thinking to use Flows in most places i would "traditionally" use Chains.

While technically i have found it works, i do wonder if there are major drawbacks like performance-issues? For now, the most annoying thing is a bug in my linter not recognizing the constraints, but i'm fine with that